# Git hub- This branch is 7 commits behind master. How to resolve this?

Tags: git, github

I'm using the web interface of the github. I cannot access command-line.

I'm facing difficulties to update my sub-branch with respect to master branch. My sub-branch is A and I tried yo update it to master branch.

I tried a pull request but files did not update.

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: We may need a bit more info: is this a single repository? Or is the master-branch in a different repository compared to the sub-branch? And which way did you attempt the pull-request? From master to sub-branch?

Comment: It's a single repository. I attempted master to sub-branch pull. @Evert

Comment: *I cannot access command-line*: why? Github is used to host git repositories. So you're supposed to use git to modify the repo. Use the command-line, or install a graphical git client. You can't do anything you would do with git using just the github web interface.

Comment: Any links to follow? @JBNizet

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Answer (score 1):

You should merge your develooment branch A into master locally and then push it (master) back into github.

The local steps are:

1. Checkout master branch
2. Merge sub branch A into master
3. Push master into origin (github)

You can do each of these steps with your preferable GUI client if you not using command line

Comment: The OP states they "cannot access command-line.". I think what you suggest here is using git commands on the command line?

Comment: Not just command line, thats way I didn't write the commands. He might working with some GIT GUI

Comment: I do not have command line. I'm using github website. No GUIs. It's a wreck. @ItayB

Comment: github now have a desktop application/ try to download it then login to your github account after finish manage all your repo.

Comment: So how did you commit?

Comment: I have two branches. Another user committed from his branch to master. Now, I have to update that to my branch. @ItayB

Comment: Are u using the same remote repository or do you have two diff? (Fork)

Comment: Same repository. There is a master branch and two sub-branches which each one of us uses. My machine has restrictions so can't install a GUI or access command line. I'm trying from github website to update my branch with respect to master. I'm unablt to do that. @ItayB

Comment: So I understand that you are working on the same remote repo.. Cant he do the merge and push to master?

Comment: Master is updated as his sub branch. Now I need to update my branch to get the latest code from master. I am not able to do that. @ItayB

Comment: It's not the right way to do it, but I think you can use the pull request mechanism to merge branch A into master. Click on new pull request, in 'base:' choose master and in 'compare:' use branch A